# Is Docker using my own system's kernel or base image's kernel?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, containers, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

Let's say I've configured and changed a few things in the kernel of my own Ubuntu 16.04. Then I've created a Docker container based on an Ubuntu 14.04. So is this container using the kernel of modified 16.04 or kernel of a clean 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no kernel in a Docker image. This is the fundamental and most important difference between a virtual machine and a Docker container.

The images namedas operating systems distributions such as ubuntu, debian, ... are not operating systems, but are rather images with filesystem structure and tools that you typicaly find in an ubuntu distribution
for example.

So in short, the docker container always uses the kernel of the host machine where it is running.